# ffmpeg converting mp4 to gif with color palette results in truncated video

Tags: ffmpeg, gif

I want to generate a gif from my mp4 movie with ffmpeg (`ffmpeg version 2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`) using a color palette. Everything works fine if I do not use a palette:

```
$ ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter_complex "scale=160:-1" out.gif
...
frame= 2003 fps=251 q=-0.0 Lsize=   21172kB time=00:01:20.12 bitrate=2164.7kbits/s    
video:21155kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.077667%
```

But using a palette like so results in `Buffer queue overflow, dropping` messages and a truncated video

```
$ ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v] scale=160:-1, split [a][b];[a] palettegen [p];[b][p] paletteuse" out.gif
....
[Parsed_paletteuse_3 @ 0xc56de0] [framesync @ 0xd1af08] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
Last message repeated 36 times
[Parsed_paletteuse_3 @ 0xc56de0] [framesync @ 0xd1af08] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
Last message repeated 106 times
...
[Parsed_palettegen_2 @ 0xc56d40] 255(+1) colors generated out of 1347441 colors; ratio=0.000189
frame=   65 fps=5.4 q=-0.0 Lsize=    1036kB time=00:01:20.12 bitrate= 105.9kbits/s    
video:1035kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.124664%
```

Comment: It does. The final output shows that only `frame=   65` were processed. `frame= 2003` were processed in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, I figured it out how to circumvent this behavior. I just need to include a fifo in the stream which is used for conversion, so that it waits until the palette is generated:

```
$ ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v] scale=160:-1 [r];[r] split [a][b];[b]fifo[bb]; [a] palettegen [p];[bb][p] paletteuse" out.gif
...
frame= 2003 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 Lsize=  804608kB time=00:01:20.12 bitrate=82268.4kbits/s    
video:804591kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.002042%
```

Comment: You don't need to use fifo if you use a modern version of ffmpeg.